# Error with Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, sessionfactory

**applicationContext.ml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
      p:url="${jdbc.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.beans.Album</value>
            <value>it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.beans.Artist</value>
            <value>it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.beans.Song</value>
            <value>it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.beans.RecordCompany</value>
            <value>it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.beans.Category</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- DAO -->
<bean id="albumDao" class="it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.daoImpl.AlbumDaoImpl">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="artistDao" class="it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.daoImpl.ArtistDaoImpl">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="categoryDao" class="it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.daoImpl.CategoryDaoImpl">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="recordCompanyDao" class="it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.daoImpl.RecordCompanyDaoImpl">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="songDao" class="it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.daoImpl.SongDaoImpl">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<!-- BO -->
<bean id="albumBo" class="it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.boImpl.AlbumBoImpl">
    <property name="albumDao" ref="albumDao"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="artistBo" class="it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.boImpl.ArtistBoImpl">
    <property name="artistDao" ref="artistDao"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="categoryBo" class="it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.boImpl.CategoryBoImpl">
    <property name="categoryDao" ref="categoryDao"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="recordCompanyBo" class="it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.boImpl.RecordCompanyBoImpl">
    <property name="recordCompanyDao" ref="recordCompanyDao"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="songBo" class="it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.boImpl.SongBoImpl">
    <property name="songDao" ref="songDao"></property>
</bean>
```

**AlbumDao** package it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.dao

```
public interface AlbumDao {

public void save(Album album) throws Exception;
public void delete(int id) throws Exception;
public void update(Album album) throws Exception;

public Album findById(int id) throws Exception;
public Album findByName(String name) throws Exception;

public List<Album> getAllAlbum() throws Exception;

}
```

**AlbumDaoImpl** package it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.daoImpl;

```
public class AlbumDaoImpl implements AlbumDao {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionFactory")
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory factory) {
    this.sessionFactory = factory;
}  

@Override
public void save(Album album) throws Exception {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;

    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(album);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        } else {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

@Override
public void delete(int id) throws Exception {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;

    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Album album = (Album) session.get(Album.class, id);
        session.delete(album);
        tx.commit();

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        } else {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

@Override
public void update(Album album) throws Exception {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(album);
        tx.commit();

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        throw e;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

@Override
public Album findById(int id) throws Exception {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Album album = null;
    try {
        album = (Album) session.get(Album.class, id);

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return album;
}

@Override
public Album findByName(String name) throws Exception {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Album album = null;
    List<Album> list = new ArrayList<Album>();

    try {
        Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Album WHERE name= :name");
        query.setParameter("name", name);
        list = query.list();
        if (list != null) {
            if (list.size() == 1) {
                album = list.get(0);
            }
        }
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return album;
}

@Override
public List<Album> getAllAlbum() throws Exception {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    List<Album> list = null;
    try {
        list = session.createQuery("FROM Album").list();

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return list;
}

}
```

Tomcat doesn't deploy the application. It says

> FAIL - Deployed application at context path /CasaDiscografica2 but
>   context failed to start

and give me that errors:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'albumDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'sessionFactory' of bean class

and

> org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'sessionFactory' of bean class [it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.daoImpl.AlbumDaoImpl]: Bean property 'sessionFactory' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Why? Thanks.

Comment: use proper bean naming conventions, change getFactory() to getSessionFactory() and setFactory() to setSessionFactory() and try

Comment: Done. Now it tells me ->

org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.daoImpl.AlbumBoImpl] for bean with name 'albumBo' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.daoImpl.AlbumBoImpl
---
Update: Of course.. I write it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.daoImpl.AlbumBoImpl instead it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.boImpl.AlbumBoImpl ... Ouch

Comment: can you edit your question with "AlbumBoImpl" code?

Comment: after changing path of AlbumBoImpl, is it working now?

Comment: Not yet..
Give me the same error..Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'sessionFactory' of bean class [it.davidefruci.casadiscografica2.boImpl.AlbumBoImpl]: Bean property 'sessionFactory' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Comment: did you change getter and setter methods of sessionFactory in AlbumBoImpl?

Comment: Yes, but it's not working yet

Comment: ok, @Jeff is correct you can remove <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/> and use only "@Autowired", it is better if you edit your question with change code of  AlbumDaoImpl to AlbumBoImpl.

Comment: can you show me AlbumBoImpl.java class?

Comment: How? Where should I post it?

Comment: add it in your question, you can remove AlbumDaoImpl.java if problem is not in that

Comment: It's not necessary. Finally, I succeeded! The problem was in applicationContext. I wrong with errate mapping for Bo beans. Now I update  the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are autowiring `SessionFactory` you don't need to also explicitly inject it in your context.

Don't forget to add `<context:annotation-config />` to your application context if you want autowiring to work.

Comment: Could you be more explicit?

Comment: You have an @Autowire annotation on session factory.  That does the same thing as the `<property name="sessionFactory" ref=... />` code in your XML (the application context).  You don't need both, but you do need to enable the annotations like I explained.